# Is it acceptable to use matzah made for Passover of one year for the next?

Tags: halacha, passover, matzah

Commercially made matzah boxes are often stamped with a year that they were produced for, like "Passover 2022". Assuming that the matzah was kept dry and remains sealed, usually in a plastic liner to a cardboard box, is it permissible to use that matzah the next year for the week of Passover and possibly even for the next year's Seder?

Comment: Perhaps you explain why it would be an issue?
The issue I can think of is stale and inedible (but that is often even the same year Matzah)

Comment: Probably from old times, but years ago my rebbi used to not allow it because of mites. I'm guessing that no longer applies, at least for the stuff well wrapped in plastic?

Comment: re: "even for next year's Seder". I heard this asked many years ago as a way of making shmura matzo cheaper for people who can't afford a new box - by reselling unused from the previous year at a deep discount.  I think the essential question is whether the לשם מצות מצוה that worked for the previous year is sufficient to work in the future or does one need a different לשמה for each year.  Never saw why there should be a problem but will have to check further.

Comment: Maybe like an issue of succah yeshana? Since there is a hekesh from Succos to Pesach? Never heard of it, but perhaps?

Answer (score 8):

The main issue in play here is the issue of מצה ישנה which is parallel to the issue of סוכה ישנה discussed in the first perek of Maseches Sukka.

Relevant sources are:

- תוספתא פסחים ב:יג - which indicates that מצה ישנה is fine for the mitzva as long at is made לשמה
- ירושלמי פסחים ב:ד, סוכה א:ב - which discuss a machlokes Beis Shammai/Beis Hillel re: מצה ישנה

See the following which indicate that מצה ישנה that was initially made לשמה is fine to use for the mitzva of matza forever after (*as long as it was kept securely free from chameitz throughout the year*):

- [https://din.org.il/2019/04/07/מצות-משנה-שעברה/](https://din.org.il/2019/04/07/%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94/)
- [https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/מצה_ישנה](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94)

Comment: matzah yeshana would only apply to the seder night where there is a mitzvah to eat matza (according to everyone other than the Rosh). the rest of pesach just has an issue of not eating chametz which last years matza is not. i know a couple of people who buy matza after pesach and save it for the next year

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue of matza flavor for the mitzva matza.  If you use last year's there may be an issue using for seder, but its not a kashrut issue.